# select2 with bootstrap theme - inside collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I cannot get the select2 dropdown to fit parent container (collapse) when initialized hidden. I understand this is not a bug, because select2 was not able to calculate the parent width. But I couldn't overcome this. I need it to be 100% to the parent.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
      <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-select2" aria-expanded="false">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse-select2">
      <select class="form-control" data-role="select2">
        <option value="1">Option #1</option>
        <option value="2">Option #2</option>
        <option value="3">Option #3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1agwbfmy/5/)

Can anybody please help?

Comment: did it work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 11, accepted):

actually quite simple solution:

**1. CSS only solution**
give `.select2` 100% width and override with `!important` like this:

```
.select2 {
  width: 100%!important; /* overrides computed width, 100px in your demo */
}
```

here's also your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1agwbfmy/6/

---

**2. style tag for select**
another way to do it, as written in [documentation](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#responsive) is to give width to `<select>` element with `style` and it will get the attribute from there:
    `<select class="form-control" data-role="select2" style="width:100%">`

---

**3. plugin configuration**
lastly, you can set the width when calling the plugin in jQuery (as written in [old docs](https://select2.github.io/options-old.html#width)):

```
$('select[data-role="select2"]').select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap',
    width: '100%'
});
```

Comment: I went with the *3*rd option as I initialize it globally and wanted every control to inherit this.

Comment: You would get the same result with 1st solution too as `.select2` would apply the width globally to all selects with that class (and as long as you use this class to bind select2 js, it would work just fine)

Comment: But I prefer JS over CSS 

Answer (score 4):

Use  `width: '100%'` property in config.

```
$('[data-role="select2"]').select2({
   width: '100%',
   ...
});
```

Comment: yours is also correct but I chose @moped's for explanation and agility. :)